# innerHTML refresh using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use innerHTML code that removes the information in this xml document where this information is in the DIV contentfile, I found the jQuery code and decided to use it, but I'm not able to update the DIV through the code. The link of the page that I am using is this
http://radiojoven.6te.net/noar.php

I leave the more javascript function I am using.

```
//http://code.google.com/p/miniajax/
function $(e){if(typeof e=='string')e=document.getElementById(e);return e};
function collect(a,f){var n=[];for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){var v=f(a[i]);if(v!=null)n.push(v)}return n};

ajax={};
ajax.x=function(){try{return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')}catch(e){try{return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')}catch(e){return new XMLHttpRequest()}}};
ajax.serialize=function(f){var g=function(n){return f.getElementsByTagName(n)};var nv=function(e){if(e.name)return encodeURIComponent(e.name)+'='+encodeURIComponent(e.value);else return ''};var i=collect(g('input'),function(i){if((i.type!='radio'&&i.type!='checkbox')||i.checked)return nv(i)});var s=collect(g('select'),nv);var t=collect(g('textarea'),nv);return i.concat(s).concat(t).join('&');};
ajax.send=function(u,f,m,a){var x=ajax.x();x.open(m,u,true);x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4)f(x.responseText)};if(m=='POST')x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');x.send(a)};
ajax.get=function(url,func){ajax.send(url,func,'GET')};
ajax.gets=function(url){var x=ajax.x();x.open('GET',url,false);x.send(null);return x.responseText};
ajax.post=function(url,func,args){ajax.send(url,func,'POST',args)};
ajax.update=function(url,elm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.get(url,f)};
ajax.submit=function(url,elm,frm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.post(url,f,ajax.serialize(frm))};

function process(xml) {
    document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=xml;
    var title = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('song')[0].title;
    var name = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('Artist')[0].getAttribute('name');
    document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=' '+name+' // ' +title;
}
function checkXml() {
     ajax.get('/NowOnAir.xml',process)
}
window.onload=function() {
    checkXml();
    tId=setInterval('checkXml()',speed)  
}
```

---

```
window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 20000);  

function refreshDiv()
{
    document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=' '+name+' // ' +title;
}
```

Comment: `window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 20000);` should probably be `window.setInterval(refreshDiv, 20000);`

Comment: @AdamKonieska I changed as you said and still not make the refresh, this will be         function refreshDiv()
{
document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=' '+name+' // ' +title;
}

Comment: That should work.  Can you build a reproducible example in a JS Fiddle?  Set `interval()` and `refreshDiv()` are shown working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/t4bdwfor/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Concepts:

Quick summary: your page generates 2 javascript runtime errors:

- ReferenceError: speed is not defined noar.php:38:3
- ReferenceError: title is not defined noar.php:9:6

Root of your problem is that you try to do something like that:

```
function test() {
    a += 1;
}
```

When you had to do something like that:

```
var a = 0; // a in global scope
function test() {
    a += 1;
}
```

Or

```
function test() {
    var a = 0; // a is now local scope
    a += 1;
}
```

### Practice:

I think that you should delete

```
<script>
window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 20000);  
function refreshDiv()
{
    document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=' '+name+' // ' +title;
}
</script>
```

because it seems that it's duplicating functionality of this code:

```
function process(xml) {
    document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=xml;
    var title = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('song')[0].title;
    var name = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('Artist')[0].getAttribute('name');
    document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=' '+name+' // ' +title;
}
function checkXml() {
    ajax.get('/NowOnAir.xml',process)
}
window.onload=function() {
    checkXml();
    tId=setInterval('checkXml()',speed)  
}
```

To make

```
window.onload=function() {
    checkXml();
    tId=setInterval('checkXml()',speed)  
}
```

work properly - you must define speed var.
To define it - you can add

```
var speed = 20000;
```

to the beginning of your script. Perhaps here:

```
<script>
var speed = 20000;
//http://code.google.com/p/miniajax/
```

This should work. Thanks for giving link to your code - that was more expressive than words ^_^. Groking this problem was fun even if this answer costed me -4 rep ^ ^

### Variant for jQuery:

Everything the same but you should load jquery library - add something like that before any other <script>:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

(more options you can find here http://jquery.com/download/ )

And now you can use all the power of jQuery. To use jQuery right you should learn documentation. To give you the taste - here is the most simple and practical update would be rewriting function **process**:

```
function process(xml) {
    $('#contentfile').html( xml );
    var title = $('#contentfile').find('song').first().attr('title');
    var name = $('#contentfile').find('Artist').first().attr('name');
    $('#contentfile').html( ' '+name+' // ' +title );
}
```

Perhaps you could rewrite your ajax to use jQuery methods for ajax. But I don't see a reason why - if the current version of ajax works just fine. If you want to anyway - then you should look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

There other functions for working with ajax in jQuery - use what is suitable for you.

Comment: I will rebuild the question differently

Comment: Have redesigned the answer, to be more precise and put the link of the page where this all work and I want to update, I experienced all the aid and could not

Comment: Made and tested Thanks! But I wonder if I with jQuery you were using would update what you intended?

Comment: Updated answer - added Variant for jQuery. What happens next is up to you)

Comment: I updated as I said, but not me can provide the data http://radiojoven.6te.net/noar.php, even put a refresh that provided me and nda, I'm doing some step wrong code?

Comment: Yep, you are doing something wrong. You have a lot of misunderstanding about how to organize HTML properly, and you have misunderstanding about what scripts do and what order should they have. To make things simple - go here and try this: http://pasted.co/715f805d (I set password to "camel") Your mistake was that you deleted &lt;html&gt; tags and head and body. I tried to sort thigs out. It should be all right now.

Comment: @Joab Sparrow I get it! Thank you for your amazing support!

Comment: Found a mistake in my code - as I can see now when I look at you website. Here is a better version - http://pasted.co/9456361d    password the same - 'camel'. Root of that mistake was that ajax library in the top of the page defined it's own $ function - and of course  it was breaking up when I tried to invoke $() like jQuery(). Duh. Now it should be better.

Comment: Already working on the site, I am very grateful for the work and patience he had to help me, thanks again